# How do I turn on Dev C++ IDE linting for C?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

[image: code image]

I want the squiggly lines under my codes in Dev C++, is that feature available in Dev C++?

Comment: Don't post the link, edit the question & post the code.

Comment: there is no code to look at,  I just want to turn on the feature.

Comment: For this IDE https://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dev-C++ capabilities are minimal and very limited. It does not have real-time syntax check but you can do it manually using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> shortcut or Execute->Syntax Check Current File.

By default it will change the error line background to color Maroon but you can change that with : Tools->Editor Options...->Colors->Error lines(top left scroll area) Then change the back/forecolors listed bellow it.

You also can change the Syntax Check shortcut to something more convenient, go to  Tools->Configure Shortcuts... Find `MainMenu > Execute > Syntax Check Current File` then click on it and enter your desired keyword.